# Include all printable characters in caesar cipher (ascii 32-126)

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, caesar-cipher

I'm looking to make a caesar cipher that includes common ASCII printable characters (character code 32-126).

My current code:

```
private static char Cipher(char ch, int key)
{
    if (!char.IsLetter(ch))
        return ch;

    char offset = char.IsUpper(ch) ? 'A' : 'a';
    return (char)((((ch + key) - offset) % 26) + offset);
}
public static string Encipher(string input, int key)
{
    string output = string.Empty;
    foreach (char ch in input)
        output += Cipher(ch, key);

    return output;
}
public static string Decipher(string input, int key) {return Encipher(input, 26 - key);}
```

(source: https://www.programmingalgorithms.com/algorithm/caesar-cipher/)

I assume I need to at least change

```
if (!char.IsLetter(ch)) *and* return Encipher(input, 26 - key);
```

to

```
if (char.IsControl(ch)) *and* return Encipher(input, 94 - key);
```

and change the modulo 26 to 94(?) but what else needs to be done? I assume the random number generator (this is for a one time pad implementation) needs to be changed as well, to 0-93 (or maybe [95](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29252574/program-to-crack-caesar-cipher)??). However, testing this gave me errors and didn't make the output the same as the input. Maybe I need to make a isLetter check as well, so the isUpper check doesn't fail for non letters. What else am I missing?

Comment: let `char offset = 32` and replace 26 with 95.

Comment: char cannot be an integer, but ```char offset=char.parse(32.tostring());``` works.

Comment: Have a look at the code for ROT47, which covers what you want to do with a fixed shift of 47.  You need to make the shift variable, not fixed.  ROT47 is the equivalent of ROT13, but for printable ASCII rather than just letters of the alphabet.

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what i'm looking for. Changed my original code to be compatible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private static char Cipher(char ch, int key)
        {
            if (char.IsControl(ch))
                return ch;

            char offset = ' ';
            return (char)((((ch + key) - offset) % 95) + offset);
        }
        public static string Encipher(string input, int key)
        {
            string output = string.Empty;

            foreach (char ch in input)
                output += Cipher(ch, key);

            return output;
        }

        public static string Decipher(string input, int key)
        {
            return Encipher(input, 95 - key);
        }
```

Comment: For the key you want to create a value in the range [0, 95) or [1, 95) if you want to exclude the especially weak key zero. Of course [1, 95) is the same as [0, 95 - 1) + 1. By the way, not much of a problem with this code, but a method `CharToIndex()` and `IndexToChar()` might be a good idea. E.g. you may want to use a special alphabet and then you can just change those two functions instead of the "entire" encryption method.

Comment: Wouldn't that make security worse? If you exclude 0 the attacker knows the character cannot be itself, meaning they have 94 choices to choose from as opposed to 95. It sounds counterintuitive but allowing 0 keys is better.

Comment: For a normal key, yes, you don't want to (have to) distinguish between strong and weak keys and yes, it can be dangerous. But as a zero key means no encryption with a chance of 1/95 I'd say in *this particular case* it is stupid to allow it :)